# How do I upgrade my SSD if I have another one installed?

Tags: ssd

On my motherboard, I only have one SSD slot and I have windows on that SSD but I trying to replace it with the 970 EVO M.2 SSD card.

How do I get windows on that new SSD card? I don't want to have to reinstall everything all over again. I have a 1 TB hard drive if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy the data of one SSD to a different SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/626862/how-can-i-copy-the-data-of-one-ssd-to-a-different-ssd)

Comment: I have done this before, backed up my data, installed the SSD (Samsung 960 2TB SSD), used the recovery USB, installed Windows, updated and recovered everything. Since it was a fresh install, small existing errors (we all have these) were corrected and the machine works splendidly

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to connect the new SSD to your PC by keeping your existing SSD untouched? then you can use disk cloning tool like "Samsung Data Migration" tool to clone your existing SSD to new SSD

Comment: How could I go about that? -- what are the possible ways of connecting my new SSD to the computer without touching my old SSD?

Comment: Either you can connect by using an external USB case; or if your PC has an extra internal port you can use that port